# vim moves cursor in tex files "randomly"

Tags: vim, latex

For some reason my vim is weird when editing tex files, and I am not sure how to solve this problem. Here is an example, where I use `|` as the location of my cursor.

```
\begin{document}
|   \title{Seminar report}
```

I then press `fS` to go to the beginning of the word `Seminar` (this works without problems). I then want to change the word to `Evaluation`, so I hit `cw` and the word is deleted and leaves me in insert mode. I type the `E` in insert mode and it looks like the following (I also added the `v` for visual effect):

```
\begin{document}
\title{ repEv|ort}
```

I am sure this is a problem in my .vimrc, but I don't even know where to start with it.

Comment: Maybe [Vim-FAQ 2.5. helps.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25891436/717124)

Comment: That was a very nice solution. In short, I tried to open vim without my vimrc or anything, and then slowly added more things. In the end, I found that the plugin `LaTeX-Box` caused the problem. Maybe because of some settings I have set. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen you should post your comment as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some problems with plugins. In this case it is caused by [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

The way I found out was to follow the link given by @mMontu
[Vim-FAQ 2.5. helps](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5).

Basically try to reproduce the problem with no vimrc loaded and gradually adding more until the problems reappeares. For me this happened, when I run vim with plugins, and after some time, specifically it was [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) and [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

A solution for the problem is not found, and I do not look for one anymore, as I will more to [vim-latex](https://github.com/lervag/vim-latex) in the near future (same authos as [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box).

Comment: You can actually link to the VIM faq.